# Loading json from external file

Tags: jquery, json

What is the best way to load an external json file in the following script?

```
function loadimages(id, data, path) {

    var x = data.imagefeed;
    var output = ""; // initialize it outside the loop

    $.each(x,function()
    {
        output += '<li><img src= "'+path+''+this.images+'" alt ="'+this.name+'"></li>';
    });
    $(id).append(output);
}
```

mydata.json

```
var info = {
    "imagefeed": [{
        "name": "rest1",
        "images": "image1.png"
    }, {
        "name": "rest2",
        "images": "image2.png"
    }]
};
```

Comment: Define external? Server? How are you planning on sending it.

Comment: Your JSON file is actually javascript. Remove the `var info = ` and the `;` at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using jQuery's ajax function:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "mydata.json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
        loadimages(id, data, path);
    }
});


function loadimages(id, data, path) {

    var x = data.imagefeed;
    var output = ""; // initialize it outside the loop

    $.each(x, function() {
        output += '<li><img src= "' + path + '' + this.images + '" alt ="' + this.name + '"></li>';
    });
    $(id).append(output);
}
```

The $.ajax() function underlies all Ajax requests sent by jQuery. Check the API out here: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Just try with:

```
$.getJSON('mydata.json', function( data ) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

However json in `mydata.json` file should be defined without `var info =` and `;` at the end.